# Bypass SSL Proxy for Microsoft Teams - Juniper SRX

Tags: juniper, juniper-srx, proxy

How can I bypass the ssl proxy for Microsoft apps like Teams on a Juniper SRX firewall?

I can see that Teams requires connectivity for somes IPs and domains (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide&redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fOffice-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2) however I have not found a way to bypass domain names with wildcard like *.teams.microsoft.com.

Does anyone know an effective way to bypass the ssl proxy for applications like Teams?

Comment: I don't think this question is about bypassing security, so much as following the Microsoft guidelines that you don't run Teams or Office through a proxy.

Comment: I understand the question as "How can I configure the Juniper SRX firewall to proxy all traffic except for teams".  @PabloXavier, can you confirm?

Comment: Hi Everybody. Yes, my concern was about how to configure SRX to proxy all traffic except Microsoft Teams. Currently I have connectivity problems in Teams with my ssl proxy configuration and I tried to bypass ssl proxy putting the Microsoft IPs in a white list. However I need a efficient way to put all domains with a wildcard like *.teams.microsoft.com in the white list.